# zeromq: PULL/PUSH client crashes after upon connection of 31. server on windows

Tags: c++, windows, tcp, zeromq

I'm experimenting with the PUSH/PULL pattern for distributed computing in a local network.
Up to now everything seemed to work out, however, I had o discover that upon the startup of the 31 worker (server) the client (the ventilator and the collector) application crashes.

Is there a limit for the connections to a certain port on windows (on MacOs X this seems not to be the case). I'm using tcp trans port and ports 5555 and 5556 as in the zeromq example. The behavior is observer for remote and local workers.

Thx

Update: heres the code (modified sample from the zmq guide)

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    zmq::context_t context(1);

    int number_of_sockets=32;       // 32 will crash, 30 will pass

    zmq::socket_t** receiver=new zmq::socket_t*[number_of_sockets];
    zmq::socket_t** sender=new zmq::socket_t*[number_of_sockets];

    std::cout<< "go"<<std::endl;
    for (int i=0;i<number_of_sockets; i++)
    {
        receiver[i]=new zmq::socket_t(context, ZMQ_PULL);
        receiver[i]->connect("tcp://localhost:5555");
    }

    std::cout<< "ok"<<std::endl;

    for (int i=0;i<number_of_sockets; i++)
    {
        sender[i]=new zmq::socket_t(context, ZMQ_PUSH);
        sender[i]->connect("tcp://localhost:5556");
    }   

    std::cout << "done" <<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I build using Mingw-w64-tdm (4.5) by the command:
`g++ -o worker.exe taskworker.cpp -L/./lib -lzmq -L/./lib/zeromq/libzmq.la -liphlpapi -lrpcrt4 -lws2_32 -lpthread`

Comment: post the code, otherwise, difficult to know what's happening

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I pinned it down to this issue [here](https://zeromq.jira.com/browse/LIBZMQ-57). The problem is, that on windows by default there is a FD_SETSIZE limit of 64. (This makes the code crash - actually for the 32. worker). FD_SETSIZE can be modified during building 0mq (CPPFLAG="-DFD_SETSIZE=1024").
Now the crashes are gone.

Comment: Interesting, just to be clear, you built 0mq on Windows originally without this flag, that's why it crashed? Is this problems limited to Windows only?

Comment: Yes, I did build 0mq using the native mingw-w64 toolchain together with msys on windows. It all went well basically. However, in contrast to the Visual Studio Makefiles the automake process did not include a definition of FD_SETSIZE. Therefore, the systeme-wide default of 64 is used. Indeed this limit is windows specific. On Linux and I guess other *nix the FD_SETSIZE is at least 1024 which would allow for 512 of the workers.